# Is there a quick way to add a site to delicious, bookmark, save it to disk, and share it on facebook - all with a single click?

Tags: bookmarks

I would appreciate any combination of these as well. Most importantly, I know that many sites get deleted, so I would just want a single click that saves it to disk *and* shares it with at least one other social media site.

Comment: IIRC, you can tell Facebook to pull from your _delicious_ feed.

Answer (score 0):

If each individual service you would like can be made into a bookmarklet, one way you could do this would be to use an auto-clickable bookmark folder in Safari (or comparable feature in another browser) which contains all the bookmarklets. Put the folder on your bookmark bar. Then, whenever you click on it, you trigger all the bookmarklets at once.

For Delicious, I use Pukka on OS X. Facebook already has a bookmarklet. For saving to disk, you could use the [PDF Download](http://www.pdfdownload.org/pdf_bookmarklet.html) plugin.

The only snag is that you can't simply add the bookmark to the browser using this method.

Comment: Oh, I just tried the PDF Download plugin. Unfortunately, it keeps giving this error message out: "We're sorry! Please try converting your web page again in a few minutes.

You've requested your conversion at a peak period and unfortunately this our servers were unable to process your request this time. Please try converting your web page to PDF again in a few minutes. "

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that many sites get deleted. To save a site, you can use [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com). It has a [Windows and Mac client](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/) (I'm using the Mac client and it is really great), a web clipper, there are also clients for mobile phones. You can manage your saved site by tags, you can search it by content. So Evernote has really nice, and the most important, practical features.